# What do the numbers in parentheses mean after the cygwin version?

Tags: cygwin

On cygwin, when I do:

```
$ uname -r
```

I get:

```
1.7.6(0.230/5/3)
```

What does the string in parentheses (0.230/5/3) mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://cygwin.com/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob;f=winsup/cygwin/uname.cc;h=479cc442acec190149c2e1c2c4cb4d64fdfcf2b6;hb=HEAD

```
  /* Cygwin dll release */
  __small_sprintf (name->release, "%d.%d.%d%s(%d.%d/%d/%d)",
                   cygwin_version.dll_major / 1000,
                   cygwin_version.dll_major % 1000,
                   cygwin_version.dll_minor,
                   snp ? "s" : "",
                   cygwin_version.api_major,
                   cygwin_version.api_minor,
                   cygwin_version.shared_data,
                   cygwin_version.mount_registry);
```

Comment: Ok.
So it's
API major version
API minor version
shared data (?)
mount registry (?)
Thanks. I guess I'll google the rest.